# How to free boot partition when only one kernel installed?

Tags: boot, partitioning

I have a 500 MB `/boot/efi` and a 256 MB `/boot` partition.

```
Filesystem                  1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                          8117320         0   8117320   0% /dev
tmpfs                         1628264      9836   1618428   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 474987640 267057928 183778672  60% /
tmpfs                         8141308     42620   8098688   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         8141308         0   8141308   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2                 241965    138155     91318  61% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                 523248     12616    510632   3% /boot/efi
cgmfs                             100         0       100   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                         1628264        80   1628184   1% /run/user/1000
```

[image]

Only one kernel installed:

```
linux-headers-4.4.0-57
linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-57-generic
```

Other times I have uninstalled older kernels and kept the last one as backup. But right now with just one kernel I'm getting 61% of `/boot` space.

The problem of upgrading to new kernels is becoming annoying. Is there anything else I can remove from this partition?

If not, is there a safe way to move contents of root partition and expand the boot partition?

**updated** with the output of `du -h *` in `/boot`:

```
1,2M    abi-4.4.0-57-generic
1,2M    abi-4.4.0-59-generic
187K    config-4.4.0-57-generic
187K    config-4.4.0-59-generic
du: cannot read directory 'efi': Permission denied
4,0K    efi
2,9M    grub/x86_64-efi
257K    grub/locale
2,3M    grub/fonts
7,8M    grub
44M initrd.img-4.4.0-57-generic
44M initrd.img-4.4.0-59-generic
du: cannot read directory 'lost+found': Permission denied
12K lost+found
180K    memtest86+.bin
182K    memtest86+.elf
182K    memtest86+_multiboot.bin
3,8M    System.map-4.4.0-57-generic
3,8M    System.map-4.4.0-59-generic
6,8M    vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
6,8M    vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic.efi.signed
6,8M    vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic
6,8M    vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic.efi.signed
```

Comment: Can you do a du -h * in /boot to show what's actaully taking space? Please paste as text, not picture.

I have three kernels on a ubuntu machine here, consuming approx 40MB per kernel, for a total of 155MB...

Comment: updated with the output of `du -h *` in `/boot`

Comment: 256MB `/boot` is ridiculous. Why you did that?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for text you can copy and paste.

Comment: @Pilot6 Apparently 256MB is the default size for `/boot` the installer creates when using LVM. And yes, it is ridiculous.